My CSS does not work properly in Safari Mobile and Chrome Mobile
I have many such elements in my site (Card system, scale down and up canimation when you click on the image, etc.). But now I will only show the button as an example.
The problem is: when you press this button in Safari and Chrome browsers, no animations are played. In that case, when I long press the button, animation plays just half and when I touch somewhere, it's completing. You see what the animation would normally be like. However, this problem never occurs in browsers like Opera.
My example button:
<style>
.button {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  outline-color: deeppink;
  transition: filter 250ms;
  tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 150px;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.button:active .front {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: transform 34ms;
}

.button:active .shadow,
.button:active .edge {
  transform: translateY(2px);
  transition: transform 34ms ease;
}

.button .edge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF7E5F, #FEB47B);
  transform: translateY(2px);
  z-index: 0;
}

.button .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: translateY(2px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.button .front {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF7E5F, #FEB47B);
  padding: 12px 25px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 1);
}
</style>
<main class="main-content" id="main-content">
<a type="submit" class="button">
            <span class="shadow"></span>
            <span class="edge"></span>
            <span class="front">Register</span>
</a>
</main>

I couldn't find a solution.

Can anyone help?
